# Can't break on exceptions in MSVC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11

I have an exception thrown from native code in Visual Studio 10. I've enabled breaking on throw for all exceptions in the debug->exceptions menu. It's a regular C++ std::runtime_error, no SEH or managed exceptions involved here. But the runtime won't break on throw. It also won't catch them- even though I explicitly caught runtime_errors, since I throw some. They're finally caught by the managed calling code. I put a breakpoint before the throw statement and I know which one is throwing and why- but still mystified as to why I can't break on it or catch it.

```
    try {
        //...
        std::for_each(...) {
            if (condition) {
                std::stringstream str;
                str << "Error: Unexpected end of file in file " << arg.first << "\n";
                str << "Unused tokens: \n";
                for(int i = 0; i < token_stack.size(); i++) {
                    auto ref = token_stack.top();
                    str << "    " << ref->contents << " at line " << ref->line << "\n";
                    token_stack.pop();
                }
                throw std::runtime_error(str.str());
            }
        });
        //...
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error& exception) {
        std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
```

The function is eventually called from managed code. I know that this throw statement is the one throwing.

Comment: Wrong tags? Should it have c++ & .NET instead of C++0x ??

Comment: @Martin: No, since all of the problem occurs in native code.

Comment: @DeadMG - yeah but it's still in the context of a managed app and it's got nothing to do with C++ **0x** whatsoever.

Comment: @Martin: It's not in the context of a managed app at all. The fact that the user of the DLL is my own managed code is irrelevant. It's a DLL exporting a C interface. If I loaded it from Lua would you call that a Lua problem? As for C++0x, this is C++0x compiled in a C++0x compiler, so it's a C++0x problem.

Comment: Have you tried loading the DLL from a native app. Are you able to break on the exception there? If it's got a simple C interface, you should be able to write a quick native test app.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a managed appliaction as you seem to imply, then I think you need to enable "mixed mode debugging". Have you checked if you can set a breakpoint in this function?

Comment: Sorry, it was implied that I put a breakpoint before the throw call, and I know which one is throwing because it broke. The regular breakpoints work fine and I have mixed mode debugging on.